# MaterialTable sends me back to the first page when a row is selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I've been struggling to get a Material Table to work the way I want it to: I need to be able to select one row at a time and use its State to manipulate its content. I've based myself off of [this site's](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling) examples (the Selected Row Styling one, to be more exact) and managed to get to this:

```
const [rowState, setRowState] = React.useState({
        selectedRow: null,
    });

const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        columns: //columns format
        data: //table content
    });

<MaterialTable
    title="User Management"
    columns={state.columns}
    data={state.data}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5,6,7]} //this doesn't seem to work at all
    onRowClick={((e, selectedRow) => setRowState({ selectedRow }))}
    options={{
         rowStyle: rowData => ({
         backgroundColor: (rowState.selectedRow && rowState.selectedRow.tableData.id === rowData.tableData.id) ? '#DDD' : '#FFF'
         })
    }}
/>
```

After some testing, it turns out the table works, and I'm able to access the selected row's content via the rowState.

However, whenever I try to select a row from any page that's not the first one, it immediately throws me back to the first page, *though the selection does appear to function normally*.

From what I've tried changing here and there, though it was obvious to begin with, the problem is in the onRowClick function. I changed it to a simple console.log and it doesn't send me back to the first page when rows from other pages are clicked (the console.log works as intended).

I think this might actually be something simple, but I'm a complete beginner when it comes to Web, so I have no idea what exactly the problem is, nor how to fix it. I would also appreciate help with this *rowsPerPageOptions* thing that I saw in the Table Pagination API page, though I'm not sure if it's supposed to be used here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to keep track of the page changes and set the table's initial page, I think you can do that using `onChangePage={(..) => ....}` and `options={{initialPage: .....}}`.

Comment: Wouldn't that create a function that would trigger anytime a page changes? Maybe I said it in a confusing way, but it is sending me to the first page when I click a row from any other page, and I don't want that to happen. I will give these props a try though, thanks!

Comment: Yes it will trigger on every page change, the idea is to store the page number and set the component's `initialPage` to that stored value, otherwise, on every render, the component will go back to the first page (default `initialPage`).

Comment: I've done a little more testing, and sadly, it seems this isn't the problem. I didn't really manage to use the `onChangePage` to change the options, but I did it manually and tried to set the `initialPage` to other numbers. Regardless, clicking a row on any other page other than the first still sends me to the first one. It seems to happen with any `setState` function, and stuff like `console.log()` or `alert()` doesn't do it. Still no idea why it's happening though.